# How to use a lambda to filter a boolean array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, java-8, java-stream

I want to split a string by `"||"` and count how many elements from the resulting array return `true` for a function `boolean isValid(String[] r)`.

I'm trying to use `Arrays.stream` to evaluate and filter the array, and finally, filter the resulting array to only keep the true values.

```
boolean[] truthSet = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+))
                           .map(r -> isValid(r))
                           .filter(b -> _whatGoesHere_)
                           .toArray(boolean[]::new);
```

In place of `_whatGoesHere`, I tried putting `b`, `b == true`, to no avail. What's the right way to achieve this?

Comment: "to no avail" - why? what is the result?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Well, I may be prematurely assuming, but my IDE thinks its a "bad return type in lambda expression. Object cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: The error is not caused by `b -> b`. You should read it. And post it. It has to do with trying to make an array of `boolean` (primitive types) from a `Stream<java.lang.Boolean>`(objects). What's the point in creating an array with only true values anyway? Wouldn't the size of the stream convey the same information? (i.e. there are N valid strings)?

Comment: No need to `map` the elements; you can use `filter` directly: `Arrays.stream(...).filter(str -> isValid(str)).count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass itself, the lambda would look like `b -> b` (because it's already a boolean:

```
 Boolean[] truthSet = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+"))
                       .map(r -> isValid(r))
                       .filter(b -> b)
                       .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

But you're getting only values, that are `true` and packing them to array - this will produce a boolean array with nothing but `true` values. Maybe you meant:

```
 String[] validStrings = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+"))
                       .filter(r -> isValid(r))
                       .toArray(String[]::new);
```

P.S.: To count the values, you can use `Stream#count`.

Comment: First part doesn't answer this question at all.

Comment: `.toArray(boolean[]::new);` won't work, since the type at that point is `Stream<Boolean>`. You could use `Boolean` instead of the primitive type...

Comment: that will return an array with all "true" - so what's the difference?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to convert it to an array of booleans, but this works too. I Eventually want to count the number of items that returned `true` for isValid, so this works too. Although, I am curious, if I DID want a boolean array, how would I do it?

Comment: @GothamCityRises, to count the number of items you don't need to collect to array, you could use `Stream.count()` or `Collectors.counting()` methods. you need to edit the question and state what is the precise requirement

Comment: Hence my comment underneath. If you want an array of booleans, then the first part is your answer.

Comment: @Andronicus no. The first snippet won't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes I noticed that and corrected my comment

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just count then you can use simple `Stream#count`

```
long count = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+"))
                       .map(r -> isValid(r))
                       .filter(b -> b)
                       .count();
```

And Since there no BooleanSteram like `IntStream, DoubleStream` etc,so you cann't convert `Stream<Boolean> to boolean[]`, in that case, you have to use `Boolean[]`

```
Boolean[] truthSet = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+"))
                           .map(r -> isValid(r))
                           .filter(b -> b)
                           .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Comment: `filter(b -> b)` would compile?

Comment: Yes, it will compile and works fine. I believe your `isValid(r)` method returns a `boolean` value

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want

```
   Boolean[] truthSet = Arrays.stream(range.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(r -> isValid(r))
            .map(s -> Boolean.TRUE)
            .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly the OP asks to split by '||' and is looking for the count, so a (minimal) viable solution would look like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "||a||a||b||a||bn";

        long count = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|")
                .splitAsStream(test)
                .filter(Scratch::isValid)
                .count();

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static boolean isValid(String r) {
        return "a".equals(r);
    }
}
```